# CoAP Too many observers

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, communication, observers, coap

I want to 'Observe' resources in a CoAP server. But What I've noticed is that after I register to observe a few resources in the server, an additional resources I try to 'Observe' throw a message saying 'Too Many Observers'

I'm using Copper (Firefox) to connect to the servers.

Is there a limit of resources that can be observed with a CoAP server? Google isn't helping me out much here. 
Am I doing something wrong myself?

Thanks.

Comment: Interesting question I never got into thta trouble but I only added a few observers. Interested to see solution for this.

Comment: I don't know if anyone else has ever had this issue. I'm just using COOJA though, in a VM. Would that be the issue at hand here?

Comment: I'm not sure what cooja, copper or coap are :(

Comment: @Noitidart I'm so sorry for the horribly late reply. Simply put, Cooja is a network-simulator. CoAP is a communication protocol and Copper is a tool in firefox to help follow and visualize the communication between two machines which use CoAP.

Comment: Interesting! Thanks for the share man

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Coap observe draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-core-observe-16#page-15) doesn't set any limits to the numbers of observers. It just adds a design note about the maximum notification rate. It is just up to the device resources.

As you can see in [this coap implementation](https://github.com/malvira/contiki-2.x-devl/blob/1b0af2a21d6f15aacb6449237e57175319c1bb0a/apps/er-coap-07/er-coap-07-observing.c) it replies "Too many observers" because the device has no more memory to allocate.

Comment: I thought as much. Thanks for confirming!